# Using EventDelegate as button press listener

Tags: javascript, rxjs, sapui5

I am using [OpenUI5](http://openui5.org/) for my frontend apps and want to use 
`Rx.Observable.fromEvent` for handle click event.

For example, I have a button and want to get benefit of the reactive programming and I am trying to use `Rx.Observable.fromEvent` as follow:

```
let oBtnEdit = this.byId("cal-edit");
      var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(oBtnEdit, "click");
      var subscription = source.subscribe(
        function (x) {
          console.log('Next: Clicked!');
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log('Error: %s', err);
        },
        function () {
          console.log('Completed');
        });
```

But I've got following error:
[image]

I do not know, what am I doing wrong. I read the doc [sap.m.Button](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html) and could not configure it out, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably problem is that RxJs's `fromEvent` expects DOM element but you are passing SAP's object.
Try to change

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(oBtnEdit, "click");
```

to

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(oBtnEdit.getDomRef(), "click");
```

Comment: I tried with `var foo = this.byId("cal-edit").getDomRef(); console.log(foo);` and the log shows me null.

Comment: @zero_coding, Actually I knew nothing about OpenUI5, so I am trying to guess. Since `getDomRef` exists then oBtnEdit is actually a Control. [Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#getDomRef) says _Some elements or controls might not have a DOM representation_ ... _due to their current state (e.g. an initial, not yet rendered control)_. Is it possible that oBtnEdit control isn't rendered yet?

Comment: it should be rendered, because the view will first get rendered after then the controller.

Comment: @zero_coding, No more ideas, sorry

Comment: Where is this code executed, e.g. life cycle event of your controller...